# Insert button into NavigationViewItem UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to use `NavigationView` as tab navigation for my UWP app, as it has appropriate styling and handles overflow well.

Now I want to add a button to each `NavigationViewItem`on the right of the label. This button should only be visible when the item is selcted.

I have achieved adding the button in the code below, but I can't figure out how to hide the button when the tab is not selected. I have tried binding the button to a bool on my data-model, which I set to `true` on `ItemInvoked`, but that didn't work.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                PaneDisplayMode="Top"
                OverflowLabelMode="NoLabel"
                IsSettingsVisible="False"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind TabItems}">

                <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TabNavigationItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                                <Button Background="{StaticResource Transparent}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE711;"></FontIcon>
                                </Button>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</NavigationView>
```

[image: Picture of NavView]

I have looked at Community Toolkit TabView, but as I handle all navigation myself, and just need a row of selectable items, `NavigationView` was a better fit for me.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I already tried

```
<Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" Visibility="{x:Bind Selected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode="OneWay"}">
```

And

```
private void NavView_OnItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.InvokedItem is TabNavigationItem t)
    {
            t.Selected = true;
    }
    Bindings.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Bindings.Update` you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `TabNavigationItem` class and fire the `PropertyChanged` event inside the `Selected` property setter. This way it should notify the UI and properly update the button visibility. Also, don't forget to un-select all the other items as well.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the button with the Visibility Property. I would create a converter for that task that takes the bool and returns the visible or collapsed value.

Comment: Starting with the Anniversary Update (August 2016), the XAML does this job automatically.    ;)